# Is there a way to create a report view of all links (<a /> tag) contained within all published content?

Tags: views

Is there a way to create a report view of links contained within all Page nodes of my Drupal site? We want a list of all hard-coded URLs (`href="https://example.com/example/example"`) but don't care about links that reference other nodes (i.e. `href="/node/12345"`).

I already know how to create a view, but I'm having difficulty understanding how to scrape each individual `<a/>` tag within a rich text field (ex. Content:Body) and then outputting those links into a table View.

Drupal 8

Comment: I think this can be done with external tools like Screaming Frog or with a server access log review and might not necessarily be related to Drupal. Everything else might be a bit cumbersome to be achieved from within Drupal, like: query all nodes, get all body fields (or other textfields as well) and check for the existence of `<a` strings, then list these nodes or their path aliases and crawl their URLs, and try to follow all link and capture the status code they return, and list them again, ufff. Alternatively you can try to monitor the Drupal log for 403/404 errors.

Comment: Thanks @leymannx these are all really helpful alternatives! I'm incredibly new to Drupal so not positive on what is and isn't possible through existing features/modules.